# MCMCglmm interaction plots in R with ggeffects-package or sjPlot-package

Tags: r, plot, bayesian, interaction, mcmc

I have done many bayesian models using the MCMCglmm package in R, like this one:

```
model=MCMCglmm(scale(lifespan)~scale(weight)*scale(littersize), 
             random=~idv(DNA1)+idv(DNA2), 
             data=df, 
             family="gaussian",
             prior=prior1, 
             thin=50,
             burnin=5000,
             nitt=50000,
             verbose=F)

summary(model)
                      post.mean  l-95% CI  u-95% CI    eff.samp    pMCMC
(Intercept)           11.23327    8.368    13.73756      6228     <2e-04 ***
weight                -1.63770   -2.059    -1.23457      6600     <2e-04 ***
littersize             0.40960    0.024     0.80305      6600     0.0415 *  
weight:littersize     -0.33411   -0.635    -0.04406      5912     0.0248 *
```

I would like to plot the resulting interaction (weight:littersize) with ggeffects or sjPlots packages, like this:

```
plot_model(model, 
           type = "int", 
           terms = c("scale(lifespan)", "scale(weight)", "scale(littersize)"),
           mdrt.values = "meansd",
           ppd = TRUE)
```

But I obtain the next output:

```
`scale(weight)` was not found in model terms. Maybe misspelled?
`scale(littersize)` was not found in model terms. Maybe misspelled?
Error in terms.default(model) : no terms component nor attribute
Además: Warning messages:
1: Some model terms could not be found in model data. You probably need to load the data into the environment. 
2: Some model terms could not be found in model data. You probably need to load the data into the environment.
```

Data is already loaded. I tried to write terms differently without the "scale(x)" term, and changed the model too to deal with equal terms, but I am still getting this error message. I am also open to plot this interaction with different packages.

My model str(model) is:

```
>str(model)
List of 20
 $ Sol         : 'mcmc' num [1:6600, 1:4] -0.814 1.215 -2.119 -0.125 -1.648 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "(Intercept)" "scale(weight)" "scale(littersize)" "scale(weight):scale(littersize)"
  ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 7e+04 4e+05 5e+01
 $ Lambda      : NULL
 $ VCV         : 'mcmc' num [1:6600, 1:3] 1.094 0.693 1.58 0.645 1.161 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "phylo." "haplo." "units"
  ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 7e+04 4e+05 5e+01
 $ CP          : NULL
 $ Liab        : NULL
 $ Fixed       :List of 3
  ..$ formula:Class 'formula'  language scale(lifespan) ~ scale(weight) * scale(littersize)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..$ nfl    : int 4
  ..$ nll    : num 0
 $ Random      :List of 5
  ..$ formula:Class 'formula'  language ~idv(phylo) + idv(haplo)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..$ nfl    : num [1:2] 1 1
  ..$ nrl    : int [1:2] 92 92
  ..$ nat    : num [1:2] 0 0
  ..$ nrt    : int [1:2] 1 1
 $ Residual    :List of 6
  ..$ formula        :Class 'formula'  language ~units
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x0000025ba05f8938> 
  ..$ nfl            : num 1
  ..$ nrl            : int 92
  ..$ nrt            : int 1
  ..$ family         : chr "gaussian"
  ..$ original.family: chr "gaussian"
 $ Deviance    : 'mcmc' num [1:6600] -262.6 -137.3 -203.6 -83.6 -29.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "mcpar")= num [1:3] 7e+04 4e+05 5e+01
 $ DIC         : num -158
 $ X           :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ i       : int [1:368] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. ..@ p       : int [1:5] 0 92 184 276 368
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 92 4
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:92] "1.1" "2.1" "3.1" "4.1" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "(Intercept)" "scale(weight)" "scale(littersize)" "scale(weight):scale(littersize)"
  .. ..@ x       : num [1:368] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 $ Z           :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ i       : int [1:16928] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. ..@ p       : int [1:185] 0 92 184 276 368 460 552 644 736 828 ...
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 92 184
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:184] "phylo1.NA.1" "phylo2.NA.1" "phylo3.NA.1" "phylo4.NA.1" ...
  .. ..@ x       : num [1:16928] 0.4726 0.0869 0.1053 0.087 0.1349 ...
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 $ ZR          :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ i       : int [1:92] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. ..@ p       : int [1:93] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 92 92
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:92] "units.1" "units.2" "units.3" "units.4" ...
  .. ..@ x       : num [1:92] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 $ XL          : NULL
 $ ginverse    : NULL
 $ error.term  : int [1:92] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ family      : chr [1:92] "gaussian" "gaussian" "gaussian" "gaussian" ...
 $ Tune        : num [1, 1] 1
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "1"
  .. ..$ : chr "1"
 $ meta        : logi FALSE
 $ y.additional: num [1:92, 1:2] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "MCMCglmm"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your `model` object?

Comment: sorry, do you mean about the str(x) of the model?

Answer (score 0):

Try to scale your predictors before fitting the model, i.e.

```r
df$lifespan <- as.vecor(scale(df$lifespan))
```

Or better, use [`effectsize::standardize()`](https://easystats.github.io/effectsize/reference/standardize.html), which does not create a matrix for a one-dimensial vector when scaling your variables:

```r
df <- effectsize::standardize(df, select = c("lifespan", "weight", "littersize"))
```

Then you can call your model like this:

```r
model <- MCMCglmm(lifespan ~ weight * littersize, 
             random=~idv(DNA1)+idv(DNA2), 
             data=df, 
             family="gaussian",
             prior=prior1, 
             thin=50,
             burnin=5000,
             nitt=50000,
             verbose=F)
```

Does this work?